# Write in ASP.NET response output stream from task continuation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a http handler which should write to output some text. Text content is retrieved asynchronously, so I want to write to response stream in the ProcessRequest method like this:

```
GetContent().ContinueWith(task => 
{
    using (var stream = task.Result)
    {
        stream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
    }
});
```

However, I get a NullReferenceException with the stack trace

```
in System.Web.HttpWriter.BufferData(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean needToCopyData)
   in System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   in System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   in System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteTo(Stream stream)
   in SomeHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ProcessRequest>b__0(Task`1 task) in SomeHandler.cs:line 33
   in System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

If I do not use ContinueWith and write response after task.Wait() - there are no errors, but, obviously it is not a solution.

```
var task = GetContent();
task.Wait();
using (var stream = task.Result)
{
    stream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

How can I eliminate this error? (.net 4.0 is used)

Comment: are you able to use a modern flavor of c#? can you do it in the `async`/`await` pattern?

Comment: the response is likely already sent by the time `ContinueWith` is invoked.

Comment: O, forgot to mention - I use .net 4.0

Comment: then that answers my question as "no". i've tagged your question to denote that.

Comment: There is a NuGet package to use async/await in 4.0: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Comment: Have you made sure that `task.Result` isn't the thing that's `null`ing out?

Comment: @eternity, are you using VS2012+ or VS2010 to compile this?

Comment: @Noseratio, I am using VS 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement `IHttpAsyncHandler`. Check ["Walkthrough: Creating an Asynchronous HTTP Handler"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

On top of that, you can use `async/await` to copy the stream (note `CopyAsync` below). To be able to use `async/await` and target .NET 4.0 with VS2012+, add [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package to your project.

This way, no threads are unnecessary blocked. A complete example (untested):

```
public partial class AsyncHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    async Task CopyAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var stream = await GetContentAsync(context))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(context.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }

    #region IHttpAsyncHandler
    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        return new AsyncResult(cb, extraData, CopyAsync(context));
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // at this point, the task has compeleted
        // we use Wait() only to re-throw any errors
        ((AsyncResult)result).Task.Wait();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion

    #region AsyncResult
    class AsyncResult : IAsyncResult
    {
        object _state;
        Task _task;
        bool _completedSynchronously;

        public AsyncResult(AsyncCallback callback, object state, Task task)
        {
            _state = state;
            _task = task;
            _completedSynchronously = _task.IsCompleted;
            _task.ContinueWith(t => callback(this), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
        }

        public Task Task
        {
            get { return _task; }
        }

        #region IAsyncResult
        public object AsyncState
        {
            get { return _state; }
        }

        public System.Threading.WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
        {
            get { return ((IAsyncResult)_task).AsyncWaitHandle; }
        }

        public bool CompletedSynchronously
        {
            get { return _completedSynchronously; }
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return _task.IsCompleted; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need. Could you describe a little lot - why we need wait task at EndProcessRequest?

Comment: @eternity, the `Wait()` is there to observe any exceptions, possibly thrown by the `Task` logic. If the task has completed successfully, the `Wait` does nothing, and the response is successfully sent to the client. Otherwise, the exception is re-thrown and propagated to ASP.NET. Note that `EndProcessRequest` is called from inside the `cb` callback, which is provided by ASP.NET and which we call from `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be based on the "context-switch" which happens when the task is executed in its own thread.

The current `HttpContext` is only available in the requests thread. You could however make a "local reference" to be able to access it (but that would not completely solve your problem - see below):

```
var outputStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
GetContent().ContinueWith(task => 
{
    using (var stream = task.Result)
    {
        stream.WriteTo(outputStream);
    }
});
```

The problem now is, that your request is very likely already done when the `ContinueWith` is executed so your stream to the client is already closed.
You need to write your content to the stream before this happens.

I need to strike the follwoing part of my answer. Http handlers are not `async`-capable in 4.0 as this neets the [`HttpTaskAsyncHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httptaskasynchandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) base-class which is not available before 4.5 => I don't know a way around the `Wait` in the `ProcessRequest` method in 4.0 when using a http handler:

<strike>I recommend using something like the following:</strike>

```
using(var result = await GetContent())
{
    stream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

and the appropriate [NuGet-Package for `await`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/).

Comment: No, the error occurs while already in `MemoryStream.WriteTo`. This means that the context was not null.

Comment: @usr: True, then maybe it is because of my second point: The stream is already closed when it gets to the `BufferData`...

Comment: That would not result in a crash inside the BCL. It would result in some proper exception.

Comment: ...and why would a `NullReferenceException` not be a "proper exception"?

Comment: Because it indicates that a bug has happened and doesn't help the caller resolve the problem. All classes in the BCL are designed not to crash with things like nullref, index out of bounds, ... They crash with descriptive messages.

Answer (score -3):

Quite recently, I had come across the similar task to write an ashx handler to put response asynchronously. The purpose was to generate some big string, perform I/O and return it back on the response stream, and thus benchmark ASP.NET with other [languages like node.js](http://www.prahladyeri.com/2014/06/php-fpm-vs-node-js-the-real-performance-battle/) for a heavily I/O bound app I'm going to develop. This is what I ended up doing (it works):

```
    private StringBuilder payload = null;

    private async void processAsync()
    {
        var r = new Random (DateTime.Now.Ticks.GetHashCode());

        //generate a random string of 108kb
        payload=new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < 54000; i++)
            payload.Append( (char)(r.Next(65,90)));

        //create a unique file
        var fname = "";
        do
        {
            //fname = @"c:\source\csharp\asyncdemo\" + r.Next (1, 99999999).ToString () + ".txt";
            fname =  r.Next (1, 99999999).ToString () + ".txt";
        } while(File.Exists(fname));            

        //write the string to disk in async manner
        using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(fname,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            var bytes=(new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ()).GetBytes (payload.ToString());
            await fs.WriteAsync (bytes,0,bytes.Length);
            fs.Close ();
        }

        //read the string back from disk in async manner
        payload = new StringBuilder ();
        //FileStream ;
        //payload.Append(await fs.ReadToEndAsync ());
        using (var fs = new FileStream (fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                   FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true)) {
            int numRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            while ((numRead = await fs.ReadAsync (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
                payload.Append (Encoding.Unicode.GetString (buffer, 0, numRead));
            }
        }


        //fs.Close ();
        //File.Delete (fname); //remove the file
    }

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        Task task = new Task(processAsync);
        task.Start ();
        task.Wait ();

        //write the string back on the response stream
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write (payload.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: This is NOT really async, as the request thread is blocked at the `task.Wait()` - to be "really async" this thread should be released during that wait (which can be achived by using `await`).

Comment: Besides @chrfin's point, passing `async void` method to `new Task(processAsync)` doesn't work the way you might think it would. This task is completed as soon as the first `await` has been reached inside `processAsync`.

Comment: @chrfin - The original question also contains the same logic that uses the Wait() method. And Wait() doesn't actually block requests on a lower level. Read this MSDN article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/15/9907713.aspx

Comment: Can someone explain WHY are you down-voting?

Comment: `And Wait() doesn't actually block requests on a lower level` - yes it does. Read your linked article again! It may not use one additional thread-pool-thread, but it definitely blocks the request thread so IIS can not execute another request with it - and that is the point of the "async" in such cases, as these request threads are limited. @down-votes: you got two down-votes and two explanations, so what else do you want?

Comment: It might have blocked that thread, but the particular thread is free to do other tasks on the wait. Moreover, if you don't use Wait(), how are you supposed to "hold on" to the requst until your I/O is done?

Comment: Again: IIS can't use the thread while `Wait` is running and thats what you should avoid. You should use `await task;` as this does release the thread back to IIS until the IO is done and returns afterwards.

Comment: @PrahladYeri, to hold the request until the I/O is done, you [implement `IHttpAsyncHandler`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24512886/1768303). Note, this holds the requests, but doesn't hold the thread. Please don't use the code you posted in production, it has a serious flaw, essentially a fire-and-forget operation in ASP.NET.